# How to properly upgrade from bootstrap 4.6.0 to 5.1 on an Angular 12 project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

We are using Boostrap 4.6.0 in Angular 12 project and we run the following command to upgrade bootstrap to 5.1.3

```
npm install bootstrap@latest
```

We got an error for the follwing files and these file are not exist

```
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group";
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/media";
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/print";
```

The image below show the scss files in the bootstrap
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I need help too

Answer (score 2):

When I did bootstrap upgrade - I used [Bootstrap Migration Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/) and applied all related changes to my projects.

Comment: I follow the documentation but they didn't mention any point related to missed files!

Answer (score 1):

It's not so clear from the document what to do with the files but I found the following:

```
//change from 
@import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group"; 
//to 
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms/input-group";
```

Dropped the .media component
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#grid-updates

Removed print styles and $enable-print-styles variable
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#sass